# how to validate nested arrays in laravel validations and merge it

Tags: php, laravel

I have a nested array in my body of request which I want to replace it with some value like below :

```
{
    "sender":
    {
        "name":"sender-name",
        "contact":
        {
            "postal_code":"123453222",
            "city":"2201",
            "latitude": 35.73845582400794,
            "longitude": 51.40889167785645,
            .
            .
            .
```

now what is the problem is that I want to merge the `city` field and just the city field, not all the contact. so what I have done so far is like below :

```
  protected function prepareForValidation()
    {
            $this->merge(['sender' => ['contact' => 'city' => $somevalue]], ['receiver' => ['contact' => ['city' => $somevalue]]]]);
        }
    }
```

but the problem here is this wants me to pass all the contact array which I don't want to merge and replace all the `contact` array I just want to merge the `city` field in that.

Answer (score 1):

```php
$rules = [
    'sender' = 'required|array',
    'sender.name' = 'required|string',
    'sender.contact' = 'required|array',
    'sender.contact.postal_code' = 'required|int',
    .
    .
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'product_size' => 'required|array',
'product_size.*' => 'required:string',
```

**you can use look like this**